# Unable to find majority of TF2 textures in hammer editor

Tags: team-fortress-2

While using the Valve's Hammer editor to create a team fortress 2 map I've run into a problem finding TF2 texture.

Theres a lot of accessible tf2 textures by typing in the filter "wall" or " "ceiling" ect... But I'm wondering if there is a tag that includes all of the tf2 texture files under one search. As it appears only a small number can be found by specific filters.

Filtering for "TF2", "tf2", and "team_fortress" only bring up a handful of skyboxes. As well typing in map specific filters come up blank.

To reiterate:
1. Does anyone know which filter name to use to bring up all the TF2 textures in Hammer Editor?
2. If not, is there any community sites that I can get a library of the complete TF2 texture?

Comment: What hammer editor are you using? From SDK tools? Or from the game folder in SteamApps?

Answer (score 1):

So I found where I went wrong. There are two filter options in the browse texture selection.

The first is filter the second is keyword.

Filter sieves through material selection not based on game and only responds to words that describe materials.

Keyword sieves through materials based on game, game type and properties of the material.

Hence placing the word "TF2" in the filter sieve left me with a blank screen.
Placing "TF2" in the keyword brought up the entire library of TF2 textures.

Furthermore if you go to TF2map.net and download the "Ultimate mapping pack" 50 more texture appear under the TF2 keyword filter.

Hope this helps all other hammer mappers out there.